# Get the maximum execution time in current environment?

Tags: php

Is there any build-in PHP function to find out the configured maximum execution time?

I'm on a shared hosting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`ini_get()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php) and get the value, e.g.

```
echo ini_get("max_execution_time");
```

possible output:

```
30
```

Comment: Strange, it gives `30` but it's 5 minutes and the script is still running, any ideas?
It's a pure php script (no `set`s)

Comment: @Webinan Do you have some sleep calls in your code?

Comment: No, it's a `file_get_contents` from a remote server, in an infinite loop.

Comment: @Webinan The max execution time is only for the script it self. Things outside of it like database, streams,  queries are not included in the max execution time

Comment: Oh! Interesting. Thanks